# cURL - in verbose mode, it does not display contents of file I am posting

Tags: curl

I am testing an endpoint that keeps responding that my request was empty.

I am just posting 100 bytes or so of xml

I went into verbose mode, but I do not see my xml going out, so perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Here is my syntax (I am on windows 10)

```
curl -X POST -d @swtest.xml --insecure \
--anyauth --user apiuser:superpass https://myserver.com/xml --verbose
```

swtest.xml contains:

```
<request method="testing.call">
    <parameters>
        <first>101</first>
        <second>301</second>
    </parameters>
</request>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it make any difference if you use `-T swtest.xml`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Tried your syntax, it made no difference I can see.

Comment: On Linux `curl -d @swtest.xml https://example.com --verbose` prints out `* upload completely sent off: 188 out of 188 bytes`. Adding more content to the swtest.xml files changes the request size e.g. `Content-Length: 761`. Maybe it's a Windows specific problem.

Comment: OK, I see this "* We are completely uploaded and fine" so that should be the indication that the payload was sent.  Thanks!